# allowing only horizontal edges (with labels) by using boxes of varying height for nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I would like to take advantage of tikz-qtree's spacing algorithm to draw (horizontal) trees of the following form

```
 S  _     C
---| |---------
   | |    B
   |a|---------
   | | A  _  U
   |_|---| |---
         |b| V
         |_|---
```

where
* both nodes and edges can be labeled
* all edges are horizontal
* the nodes are made up of boxes of varying height.

Actually, I would also like to extend this to graphs that no longer are trees as in the following example

```
 S  _        C
---| |---------------
   | |    B     _
   |a|---------| | V
   | | A  _  U |c|---
   |_|---| |---|_|
         |b|
         |_|---------
                X
```

Any ideas how to extend tikz-qtree in this direction?  Maybe other tikz-related packages are better suited for this purpose, if so, please let me know.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using my tikz-based tree drawing package, `forest`. (Available at CTAN.)

I will admit, however, that drawing what you want is not trivial. First the code and the result, then the comments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  horizontal/.style={
    edge node/.style={edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize]{##1}}},
    for tree={grow'=0,anchor=center,draw,s sep=3ex,align=center,
      if n children=0{tier=leaf}{},
      parent anchor=east,
      edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor|-.child anchor)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
      before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
      fit=rectangle,
    }
  }
}
\begin{forest} horizontal
  [
    [a,minimum height=12ex
      [,edge node=C]
      [,edge node=B]
      [b,minimum height=7ex,edge node=A
        [,edge node=U]
        [,edge node=V]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\quad
\begin{forest} horizontal,
  [
    [a,minimum height=12ex,s sep=1ex
      [,edge node=C]
      [\phantom{c},name=c1,tier=c,node options'={},edge node=B,s+=2ex
        [,edge node=V,before computing xy={s-=3ex}]
      ]
      [b,minimum height=7ex,edge node=A
        [\phantom{c},edge node=U,name=c2,tier=c,node options'={},
          [,phantom]
        ]
          {\node[fit=(c1)(c2),draw,inner sep=0]{c};}
        [,edge node=X]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

About the first picture. Style `horizontal` defined in the beginning will make it reasonably easy to draw the tree (it makes edges horizontal, defines style `edge node` for drawing labels, makes all the leaves align, and makes empty nodes into coordinated), but the minimum height of the nodes is not computed automatically. (This seems to be a common desire, so I'm thinking how this could be done.)

About the non-tree. The package was not really meant for these ... so this picture is necessarily done as a "hack": edges B and U end in "phantom" nodes c1 and c2; an extra node is fit over both; the position of edges V (which formally belongs to c1 node) and B adjusted manually.